# how to get the full credit card number in my observer class on sales_order_save_before event?

Tags: magento-1, payment-methods, authorize.net, credit-card

I wanna get the credit card number when the user hit the place order button. Right now I am using this event: `sales_order_save_before` and using this code to get the card number but gets no value. 
It's possible???

**NOTE: I am using authorize.net and direct post payment methods.**

```
$session  = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
            $quote_id = $session->getQuoteId();
            $quote  = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($quote_id );
            $paymentData = $quote->getPayment()->getData();
            $cc_number = Mage::getModel('payment/info')->decrypt($paymentData['cc_number_enc']);
            echo $cc_number;  // getting no value here!!!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No, you can retrieve only last four credit card digits from order.**

### If you just need to full credit card number. Please purchase an extension from Magento 2 marketplace

```
//***if orderid=1001;***

$orderId=1001;
$order = $this->order->load($orderId);
$expmonth=$order->getPayment()->getCcExpMonth();   *//get expirymonth* 
$expyear=$order->getPayment()->getCcExpYear();      *//get expiryyear*
$cclast4=$order->getPayment()->getCcLast4();        *//get expiry last four digit from card*
```

**It worked like charm**